# Stop SQL Server listening on Remote Ports

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

How do I 'lock down' my SQL Server 2005 installation to not listen on remote ports?

My SQL Server 2005 database instances are only used locally on the machine, so I want to prevent it listening on remote ports for security purposes, but do not want to do it via a firewall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Client Configuration manager, see the section on SQL Native Client Configuration.

In the Client Protocols, disable all but "Shared Memory".

You may also have firewall ports open for port 1433 (if you had the TCP/IP client protocol). These could be disabled too.

Comment: Effectively this is reverting to the initial config that you get in SQL express.

Comment: Cheers, I haven't forgotten this question, I just haven't had the time to test your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn off remote connections in `SQL Server Management Studio`

[image]

Comment: Cheers, I haven't forgotten this question, I just haven't had the time to test your suggestion!